# Which name allow us to serach App from playstore Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Application PackageName is com.mypackage.android
and my solution name is MyApplication

so when I search on "mypackage" from playstore then my app showing.
but how to change the Searchable name from Google Play Console?

Comment: Do you want to _change app name_ or want have _some additional characters_ to search app?

Comment: yes.How to do this?

Comment: You can add the App Name and also add the keywords in the keyword section on play store listing

Comment: You are confusing me.. I have asked you two questions in above comment please read my comment carefully and answer in proper way. Thank you.

Comment: only add additional character to search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give some alternate keywords to your app to boost up searching, you all need to do it from *Google play console*.

- You can add keyword to your app Title.
- You can add keywords to app description as well.
- In setting of *Google play console*, in *Developer name* you can give keyword. It helps for searching app(not recommended)
- To search app easily in play store use some unique or tough characters. Even good rating and more downloads can increase SEO.

To change app name- Select app in google play console-->Setting-->Title.

Hope it helps.